# appcfg.py upload_data entity kind problem

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-patch

I am developing application on app-engine-path and I would like to upload some data to datastore. 
For example I have a model

models/places.py:

```
class Place(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    longitude = db.FloatProperty()
    latitude = db.FloatProperty()
```

If I save this in view, kind() of this entity is "models_place".
All is ok, Place.all() in view work fine.

**But:**

If I upload some next row using appcfg.py upload_data, the kind() of this entities is Place.

loader.py look like this:

```
import datetime, os, sys
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader

libs_path = os.path.join("/home/martin/myproject/src/")
if libs_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, libs_path)
from models import places

class AlbumLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
      bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'Place',
                                 [('name', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                  ('longitude', float),
                                  ('latitude', float),
                                 ])
loaders = [AlbumLoader]
```

and command for uploading:

```
python /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=places_loader.py --kind=models_place --filename=data/places.csv --url=http://localhost:8000/remote_api /home/martin/myproject/src/
```

Comment: This is happening because you're using App Engine Patch, which modifies the Model class to include the namespace in the kind name - but only if it's been imported.

Answer (score 1):

I found resolution:

places_loader.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import bulkload

class PlaceLoader(bulkload.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkload.Loader.__init__(self, 'models_place',
                               [('name', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                ('longitude', float),
                                ('latitude', float),
                               ])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bulkload.main(PlaceLoader())
```

app.yaml:

```
- url: /load
  script: places_loader.py
```

and command:

```
python /usr/local/google_appengine/bulkload_client.py --filename data/places.csv --kind   models_place --url http://localhost:8000/load
```